# nav to other html div with data-toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I have 2 html files

`index.html` and `services.html`

On services.html I have

```
<a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#ds-tab">Data Science</a>
<a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#ai-tab">AI</a>

<div class="tab" id="ds-tab">
   <p>DS section </p>
</div>

<div class="tab" id="ai-tab">
   <p>AI section </p>
</div>
```

It works fine on services.html

But if I am on `index.html` and I have a link as

```
<a href="services.html#ai-tab">AI Section</a>
```

It doesnt work it just navigates to the page but doesnt show the div I am refering to.

I tried doing something like this but it doesnt work too.

```
<a data-bs-toggle="tab" href="services.html#ai-tab">AI</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a data-target attribute to the AI Section link, and set it to the id of the ai-tab div:

```
<a data-target="#ai-tab" href="services.html">AI Section</a>
```